# How to add 2 variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to add two variables which have numeric values using javascript.

```
var seconds = 1100;
var time = 300;
 var newV = seconds + time;
   $('.show').html(newV);
```

But it is saying undefined

thanx

Comment: what says? show me code that says "undefined". Also, you are speaking about plain JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: First of all - there is no jQuery staff, and second - your code is working: http://jsfiddle.net/guVVa/

Comment: this is the code that says undefined .... lemme edit it to make more sense

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: Look in the debug console or error console and see exactly which line is reporting an error and exactly what the error message is.  This is basic debugging to see what the error is.  You have to determine in the console WHAT is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/n9NcY/

This HTML is probably what you were missing

```
<div class="show"> </div>
```

your code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var seconds = 1100;
  var time = 300;
  var newV = seconds + time;
  $('.show').html(newV);
});
```

Comment: I hereby award you the totally unofficial and honorary **Clairvoyance** badge. Don't check your profile, it won't be there, but thanks for taking your time to work though a very ambiguous question.

Comment: @Tim Post The crystal ball predicted an angry man comment too.